# Update a new table column incrementing the value in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to order the entries in my table and they will be reordered by the user later so I don't want to use the ID. I have just added the :order column and the values are currently all nil. I know I can give them all the same value using update_all but how can I give each row a value one higher than the last (e.g. 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc)?

I am using rails 3.2.

Comment: You can loop and update each one individually. or why dont you update the field with their id value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upload your `order` fields into your migration. If you have a lot of records, consider wrapping it into a transation:

```
Class.transaction do
  Class.each_with_index do |record, index|
    # index will start at 0 which is probably not what you want
    record.update_attribute :order, index + 1
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes indeed, I just updated answer according to your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the `@mdemolin` answer *in rails we generally use **seeds** to populate database*, so you can also **make a rake task** and update your order values there. In your **db/seeds.rb** file you can do:

```
users = User.all
users.each_with_index do |user, index|
  user.update_attribute(:order => index+1 )
end
```

and then **run rake db:seed** in your terminal

Comment: `use seeds to populate database` but OP need update exist records. This case more about migrations.

Comment: @PhilidorGreen it'll work in existing record as well, after all a seed file is only a ruby file

Comment: Oh, I didn't say that it doesn't work. But after all this not rails convention.

Comment: @PhilidorGreen He hasn't mentioned anything about migrations, in fact if you look at this question it says `I have just added the :order column and the values are currently all nil` so he does want to populate it with values

Comment: Good practice update exists records in migration. Just know it.

Comment: @PhilidorGreen sorry but what difference does it make, can you please explain? I'm novice in that area and would love to learn something new :)

Comment: i don't explain anything. Just read [doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) carefully